# SARA-R5 AWS Unable to connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, module, lte, sparkfun

I am trying to develop an application that needs GPS and mobile connection to AWS. For this I am using the SARA R5 AWS (The Sparkfun KIT-21229) I have followed the guide from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot-expresslink/latest/gettingstartedguide/elgsg-register-account.html and also the application note UBX 22017004. But everytime I try the AT+CONNECT, after a few minutes I get "ERR14 2 UNABLE TO CONNECT Network registration failed. For further details, refer to AT+DIAG CEER" That its not the expected error of certificate missing. I have searched and haven't found any solution, anyone could help me, please?

Log:

```
AT
OK
AT+CONF Endpoint=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iot.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com
OK
AT+CONF? Certificate pem
OK0 pem
AT+CONNECT
ERR14 2 UNABLE TO CONNECT Network registration failed. For further details, refer to AT+DIAG CEER
```

Thank you!